# Working with .a library in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, static-libraries

I have to use an external library with '.a' extensión but I do not have any idea how to use it. I am totally lost, I don´t know if I have to import it or not and if I have to imported I don´t know how.

How can I use this library in my project?

Answer (score 1):

When we want to invoke native library in Android apps, we can only use dynamic library, which usually ends with **.so** extension.

So that means you have to build a dynamic library based on **.a** file.